# How do I prevent a php form from deleting values during validation?

Tags: php

I have a basic html form with input and select form fields. How do I prevent the form from deleting all of the values during the validation process? This is assuming the form returns validation errors.

Comment: What exactly do you use to validate the form? If it's pure simple php, just set the value field to the get or post parameters you send when redisplaying the form.

Comment: @mindw0rk how would I do that for <option> tags if they already have a value attribute that is being used to insert data in db?

Comment: each <option> has the attribute selected="selected". If you have a function that loops and generates your select input, just check each option if the value of it is equal to what was posted and append the "selected" attribute to the tag. Otherwise if your form is static, you'll have to put some code on each option tag to check whether their value was posted and append the same piece of selection string. There are a lot of html helper snippets that do the same exact thing.

Answer (score 3):

The form won't delete values. When the form is submitted, the browser will make an HTTP request to the server. The server will respond with (probably) an HTML document.

If that HTML document is a duplicate of the original form with some added error messages, then that is what the browser will display.

If you want the data to be preserved, then the HTML document you generate in response to the form submission needs to include the data (mostly via the `value` attribute which applies to most form controls).

Answer (score 0):

The form is not deleting anything .. input is not automatically restored in a form on submission since you are redirecting to the same page.  You need to store the values on a persistence layer (`_SESSION` or a DB) and write them back out to the form once you have initially acquired them.